# How can I get all npm install logs and write them in java cli application?

Tags: java, npm, picocli

I'm building a command Line application with java picocli that basically wraps npm, maven, git, azure, and some utility commands I want to have pre-done. My issue is when for example npm install is run, it prints a whole array of stuff like warning about all the stuff it installed and logs as well as that progress bar that writes a load of stuff. Is there any way I can emulate that to my app? Now I have this to run a process:

```
protected static void run(String dir, String... strings) {
        try {
            var process = new ProcessBuilder(strings).directory(new File(dir)).start();
            process.waitFor();
            write(process.getInputStream(), System.out);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void write(InputStream stream, PrintStream out) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(line);
        out.println(buffer.toString());
    }
```

Is there any way I can get those other prints as well as the progress bar? Right now I just get the final like 5 lines that say the number of vulnerabilities after installing?

Comment: Do you want to get the log of **npm install** and append it to your java app?

Comment: yes, as much as possible, basically what i have just prints the final parts with the vulnerabilities description

Comment: Is the rest of the output going to standard error?

Comment: Nope, i dont know where it goes if it goes somewhere